# Can I get rid of "mut" here?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I have a vector of strings and I want to extract some data from them and create a structure out of it. It looks something like this:

```
let mut my_struct = MyStruct::new(0, 0, 0);
let regex1 = Regex::new("...");
let regex2 = Regex::new("...");

for s_iter in my_str_vec.iter() {
    if regex1.is_match(s_iter) {
        // parsing the value
        // .........
        let var1 = regex1.captures("....");

        // and assign it to to a field of the struct instance
        my_struct.field1 = var1;
    }

    // do the same thing for other fields each step in the loop
    // each step only one regex gets triggered

    if regex2.is_match(s_iter) {
        // parsing the value
        // .........
        let var2 = regex12.captures("....");

        // and assign it to to a field of the struct instance
        my_struct.field2 = var2;
    }
}

// now "my_struct" is now completely initialized
```

As you can see, I have to use `mut` for the structure. Is there any way to do that without `mut`? I want to be able to initialize the struct all at once, without `mut`. Or I can consider other options without `mut` also.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons for asking, but do note that in Rust `mut` is not really frowned upon - it just isn't the default and shouldn't be used when not necessary. It's often the case that making something mutable will make the rest of the code simpler and faster, and this is something Rust encourages.

Answer (score 2):

In a purely functional language, you would need to define a recursive function. In Rust, it would look like this:

```
fn parse(my_str_vec: Vec<&str>) -> MyStruct {
    let my_struct = MyStruct::new(0, 0, 0);
    let regex1 = Regex::new(...);
    let regex2 = Regex::new(...);

    fn process_next<I>(regex1: Regex, regex2: Regex, mut str_iter: I, my_struct: MyStruct) -> MyStruct
        where I: Iterator, I::Item: AsRef<str>
    {
        match str_iter.next() {
            Some(s_iter) => {
                let my_struct = if regex1.is_match(s_iter.as_ref()) {
                    let var1 = regex1.captures("var1");
                    MyStruct { field1: var1, ..my_struct }
                } else if regex2.is_match(s_iter.as_ref()) {
                    let var2 = regex2.captures("var2");
                    MyStruct { field2: var2, ..my_struct }
                } else {
                    my_struct
                };

                process_next(regex1, regex2, str_iter, my_struct)
            }
            None => my_struct
        }
    }

    process_next(regex1, regex2, my_str_vec.iter(), my_struct)
}
```

Note that there's still a `mut` in this code: we have to define `str_iter` as mutable, because calling [`next()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) requires the receiver to be mutable.

While the inner function is tail recursive, Rust does not guarantee tail calls, so it could crash with a stack overflow if the input is too large. Personally, I'd rather use `mut` here, as in your original code, especially since `mut` in Rust implies no aliasing, which eliminates a whole class of potential bugs.